# How to add multiple new Lines in Angular-cli with dynamic Text

Tags: angular5

My whole App read the text from a JSON file. When I try to add a 
 on the Text like...

```
{
  "welcome": "Hello <br> This is a test."
...
}
```

the line will not break.

The output in Chrome console:

[image]

I think the console does not show this correctly. When I copy the Element and check that on an editor I get following.

Hello <br> This is a Test.

We can correctly output the characters <> in angular 5!

Answer (score 4):

OK, found the solution...

in html use style="white-space: pre;"
and in JSON break the line with "\n" that's it.

```
<p style="white-space: pre;">
 {{MyHTMLText}}
</p>
```

or add textarea...

CSS

```
textarea.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  resize: none;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea class="content"
          disabled>
   {{MyText}}
</textarea>
```

Comment: +1 because it guided me to the solution. In my case, the text spilt out of `<div>`. `white-space: pre-wrap;` worked like a charm.